# How do I specify the external IP when using iptables masquerade?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I'm using this rule to allow internet access through OpenVPN:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However traffic via the VPN is coming from the box's primary IP. eth0 has a /29 available to it - how do I specify a different external IP?

Or is there is a better solution than masquerade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SNAT instead if you want to specify a public address.  The SNAT rule will be almost the same, just add a `--to-source ipaddr` with the public IP you want.

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source ipaddr
```

Comment: Cheers, that works perfectly! Also noticed I had to remove a rule `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` that I had for some reason